# Webview is not showing anything

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I am trying to load UIWebView on detailview when users tap in masterView Table. But somehow my UIWebView is not showing anything.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *manualURL = self.detailItem;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:manualURL];
[self.manualWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

I have also tried to check the value of url in debugger by printobject (po url) its showing correct url address but webview is still empty.

I just found out that if I put whole address like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/london then its working but if I put anything like www.google.com then its not. Any explanation ?

Comment: My favorite question: Have you made sure that your webview outlet is properly connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was just fine the problem was with the url. I was pulling out urls from plist and in Plist they were stored as "www.xyz.com" and when I replaced them with "http://www.xyz.com" it worked fine. Still don't know why it behaves in that way.